# Calculate the probability of error of two vectors

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, probability-distribution-function

I am trying to calculate the probability of error of two vectors, for example the first one is transmitting a modulated data $x$ with modulation order $M$ as following $y_1 = [x \ \ 0]^T$ while the other one is $y_2 = [x \ \ x]^T$.
It means the first one is sending the modulated data once either in first value or second value while other value is forced be zero, and the other vector is sending the same modulated data twice.

Assume that signal is transmitted via OFDM system and affected by Rayleigh channel and also AWGN. After equalizing the channel with the assumption it is perfectly known, the received signal is $\hat{y}$. Performing Maximum likelihood detector, the index of active subcarriers and modulated signal $x$ can be performed as follows:

$\left ( \hat{a} \ \ \hat{x} \right ) ={ \textrm{arg }}\underset{a, x}{\mathrm{min }}\left \| y - \hat{y} \right \|^2$

Where $\hat{y} = ax$, and $a$ is the index of active subcarrier, and $y$ is the set of transmitted signal which might include either $y_1$ or $y_2$

So, I need to derive the error probability of the received signal $\hat{y}$ which includes the index of the subcarrier transmitting the modulated data and the modulated data itself.

Comment: There's no "probability of error" involved here at all – a transmitter doesn't make any errors! So, you need to *define your receiver*, and you will also need to define what happens to the signal between transmitter and receiver, e.g. noise! So, your problem statement is sadly uncomplete!

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry for that,  it's updated now.